Pytest: Spy of magic method __call__
For use in Pytest, I would like to create a spy of the magic method __call__ of a class.
Here is a minimal example. Code base:
import pytest
from pytest_mock import MockFixture, MockType


class A:

    def __call__(self, x) -> None:
        print("__call__", x)


class B:

    def __init__(self, a: A) -> None:
        self.a = a

    def apply_a(self) -> None:
        self.a(42)

Test code:
@pytest.fixture
def a() -> A:
    return A()


@pytest.fixture
def b(a: A) -> B:
    return B(a)


@pytest.fixture
def a_application_spy(mocker: MockFixture, a: A) -> MockType:
    return mocker.spy(a, "__call__")


def test_apply_a(b: B, a_application_spy: MockType) -> None:
    b.apply_a()
    assert a_application_spy.called

The test test_apply_a fails.
The reason seems to be that the method __call__ is a magic method, which is used implicitly. The test succeeds if the implementation of B.apply_a is changed to
    def apply_a(self) -> None:
        self.a.__call__()

Is there a possibility to create the spy without having to change the code base?

This is a simple case of spying the wrong thing.
Instead of:
return mocker.spy(a, "__call__")

You want:
return mocker.spy(A, "__call__")


It seems that you are right, but I don't understand the reason. Can you add an explanation, please?
If the method was called call instead of __call__, my variant would work perfectly. Also, the documentation suggests to use instances instead of classes.

It's a matter of understanding the descriptor protocol. If the method was named call you would be invoking it with a.call(), not a(), so a.call would invoke a descriptor to create/return a bound method. In your case the equivalent to a() is more like A.__call__(a), so it's A.__call__ that we need to spy.

Sorry to bother you, bot I don't get it. I added an argument x for better debugging. If I add an analogous method call to A, then print(a.__call__) and print(a.call) indicate that both methods are bound to a. In addition, for x = 42, the three statements a(42), a.__call__(42) and A.__call__(a, 42) all have the same effect (they print "__call__ 42" to the stdout), and the two statements a.call(42) and A.call(a, 42) have the same effect (they print "call 42" to the stdout).

I think I understood it now by printing a_application_spy.call_args: With mocker.spy(a, "__call__"), I get None. With mocker.spy(A, "__call__"), I get call(<A object at ...>, 42). And if I replace __call__ with call in the implementation of B: With mocker.spy(a, "call"), I get call(42). With mocker.spy(A, "call"), I get call(<A object at ...>, 42).
So it seems that for ordinary methods, I can use both the instance and the class. But implicit invokations of magic methods (or at least __call__) are internally resolved to the verbatim class variants.
Thanks @wim!

Yes, I think you got it more or less (difference between functions and methods). It is the action of the "dot" that makes the a.__call__ into a bound method, that's the descriptor protocol in action. But since you want to spy a(), as far as mocker is concerned you have to patch the function which that eventually goes into, which is A.__call__.
